# Kevin Lindsey 2D.js & Google's js Chart Library throwing error

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

While I am trying Kevin Lindsey's Library(2D.js) in Google Chart page, it shows error.

While using both independently. It's fine. But while using together, it throws error.

**Error-With Adding Library**

[image: With Library]

**No error-Without Adding Library**

[image: Without Library]

***index.html***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="IntersectionUtilities.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/2D.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Month', 'Planned', 'Actual'],
                ['Mar-09', 0, 0],
                ['Apr-09', 0.00151929523245614, 0.0146364816491228],
                ['May-09', 0.0124579992774453, 0.033083223565764],
                ['Jun-09', 0.0309118903087972, 0.0399847460110481],
                ['Jul-09', 0.0480232261315493, 0.0528615348913121],
                ['Aug-09', 0.0746095488858985, 0.0746095488858985],
                ['Sep-09', 0.114817895883872, 0.114817895883872],
                ['Oct-09', 0.15656355950235, 0.15656355950235],
                ['Nov-09', 0.201191315395714, 0.201191315395714],
                ['Dec-09', 0.249953985795909, 0.249953985795909],
                ['Jan-10', 0.300610725230242, 0.291777],
                ['Feb-10', 0.352760685392659, 0.325312],
                ['Mar-10', 0.407625647744274, 0.381489],
                ['Apr-10', 0.46528112323502, 0.4351855],
                ['May-10', 0.528717160962978, 0.495409],
                ['Jun-10', 0.584399247373237, 0.550191],
                ['Jul-10', 0.635457755525976, 0.600298],
                ['Aug-10', 0.682892477014679, 0.648201],
                ['Sep-10', 0.729331361477304, 0.697411],
                ['Oct-10', 0.775106438820932, 0.734041],
                ['Nov-10', 0.817568962427278, 0.767669],
                ['Dec-10', 0.846990001291726, 0.794953],
                ['Jan-11', 0.875267241723479, 0.822881],
                ['Feb-11', 0.899415677281897, 0.850654],
                ['Mar-11', 0.920258084250725, 0.874219],
                ['Apr-11', 0.940673161780297, 0.890452],
                ['May-11', 0.954714998220322, 0.904493836440025],
                ['Jun-11', 0.963550955141021, 0.913329793360723],
                ['Jul-11', 0.967332955141021, 0.917111793360723],
                ['Aug-11', 0.969564955141021, 0.919343793360723],
                ['Sep-11', 0.970013508051817, 0.919792346271519],
                ['Oct-11', 0.97001548091064, 0.919794319130343],
                ['Nov-11', 0.970016467340052, 0.922854415668406],
                ['Dec-11', 0.970017782579267, 0.924759340129943],
                ['Jan-12', 0.970018988215215, 0.926288849483787],
                ['Feb-12', 0.970021531011032, 0.927958856966862],
                ['Mar-12', 0.97109277051861, 0.930075264449937],
                ['Apr-12', 0.972014608376272, 0.932972073429627],
                ['May-12', 0.973572412616675, 0.937072565402547],
                ['Jun-12', 0.978533485751583, 0.943825144858543],
                ['Jul-12', 0.986623440672842, 0.954049910192197],
                ['Aug-12', 1, 0.971123151131509]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'S Curve \'Project-Trial\'',
                crosshair: { trigger: 'both' },
                vAxis: { title: 'Progress (%)' },
                colors: ['#001122', '#33cc33', '#ffcc66', '#ff3300', '#001122'],
                connectSteps: false,
                seriesType: 'line',
                lineWidth: 2,
                series: { 0: { type: 'line', lineDashStyle: [2, 2] } },
                isStacked: false
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
            var s = this.document;
            loadShapes(s);

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

***IntersectionUtilities.js***

Functions in switch block are called from *2D.js*. Hence, while adding 2D.js in HTML header, Google charts are not rendered & throwing error. else charts are rendered fine & Kevin's library is working fine INDEPENDENTLY.

```js
var svgns  = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var points = new Array();
var shapes = new Array();


function loadShapes(s) {
    svgDocument = s;
    var children = getElementByXpath("//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]").childNodes[0].childNodes[4].childNodes[1].childNodes[2].childNodes;

    for ( var i = 0; i < children.length; i++ ) {
        var child = children.item(i);

        if ( child.nodeType == 1 ) {

                // ignore value for now
                var shape;

                switch ( child.localName ) {
                    case "circle":  shape = new Circle(child);    break;
                    case "ellipse": shape = new Ellipse(child);   break;
                    case "line":    shape = new Line(child);      break;
                    case "path":    shape = new Path(child);      break;
                    case "polygon": shape = new Polygon(child);   break;
                    case "rect":    shape = new Rectangle(child); break;
                    default:// do nothing for now
                }


                if ( shape != null ) {
                    shape.realize();
                    shape.callback = showIntersections;
                    shapes.push(shape);
                }

        }
    }
    showIntersections();
}


/*****
*
*   showIntersections
*
*****/
function showIntersections() {
    if ( shapes.length >= 2 ) {
        var inter = Intersection.intersectShapes( shapes[0], shapes[1] );

        info.data = inter.status;
        for ( var i = 0; i < inter.points.length; i++ ) {
            var coord = inter.points[i];

            if ( i >= points.length ) {
                var point = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgns, "use");

                point.setAttributeNS(
                    "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
                    "href",
                    "#intersection"
                );
                svgDocument.documentElement.appendChild(point);
                points.push(point);
            }
            points[i].setAttributeNS(null, "x", coord.x);
            points[i].setAttributeNS(null, "y", coord.y);
            points[i].setAttributeNS(null, "display", "inline");
        }

        for ( var i = inter.points.length; i < points.length; i++ ) {
            points[i].setAttributeNS(null, "display", "none");
        }
    }
}

/*****
*
*   getting svg-paths for intersection
*
*****/

function getElementByXpath(path) {
    return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  }
```

Comment: Kevin's Library : http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/index.htm

Comment: please share a sample of the actual code used to draw the chart(s) (please not in a pic). -- most likely `this` is the problem, need to see in which context, `this` is used...

Comment: @WhiteHat Code update...